How to find an analytic function with given real part of the differential?
This question came in my university exams last year.

Let $P$ and $Q$ (functions $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$) be continuous and have continuous first partial derivatives in a (simply connected) region $\mathcal R$. Suppose that for every simple closed curve $C$ in $\mathcal R$, we have: $$ \oint_C Pdx+Qdy=0.$$
(a) Prove that there exists an analytic function $f(z)$ such that $\Re\{f(z)dz\}= Pdx+Qdy$ is an exact differential. (b) Determine $p$ and $q$ in terms of $P$ and $Q$ such that $\Im\{f(z)dz\}=pdx+qdy$ and verify that $\oint_C pdx+qdy=0$. (c) Discuss the connection between (a) and (b) and Cauchy's theorem.

The words in parenthesis are my addition and weren't originally part of the question.
My attempt:
I've done a previous exercise from which I come to the conclusion that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ using the fact that $\oint_C Pdx+Qdy=0$.
I assume that $f(z)=u+iv$ has the property that $\Re\{f(z)dz\}= Pdx+Qdy$ then $$f(z)dz = (u+iv)(dx+idy)=(u\,dx-v\,dy)+i(v\,dx+u\,dy)$$
So, comparing, we should have $u=P$ and $v=-Q$. But then looking at Cauchy-Riemann equations, $u_x=v_y$ is not satisfied though $u_y=-v_x$ is satisfied.
I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't want or expect any one to write a complete solution to three parts of this question. I want a hint on how to proceed or help me interpret this question correctly if I'm doing something naive.

As it is written the statement is false.
As you have shown $Pdx+Qdy$ is the real part of a analytic complex form iif
$$
P_x+Q_y=0
$$
But if $P=2xy^2,Q=2x^2y$, than the form is exact as it is $\nabla (x^2y^2) \cdot (dx,dy)$,but
$$
P_x+Q_y=4(x^2+y^2) \ne 0
$$
Maybe there is some other condition?
